# Bigbluebutton 2.6.10 cannot load presentation from URL (local loopback error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-20.04, bigbluebutton

I am running a BBB 2.6.10 Server on Ubuntu 20.04.6  with GreenlightV2.
I can upload a custom presentation via greenlight to a conference room.

When I start the conference, i can see in the logs that BBB is trying to access the preuploaded presentation. However it throws an error complaining that "127.0.1.1 is a loobpack address"

Logs:

````
2023-09-05T09:32:09.454+02:00 DEBUG o.b.web.controllers.ApiController - module config found: [presentation]
2023-09-05T09:32:09.454+02:00 DEBUG o.b.web.controllers.ApiController - ApiController#downloadAndProcessDocument(https://bbb-conference.secunet.de/b/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBYjQ9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--d3198043c54f5555051d8efc6077c711ee7a2b71/CHANGE_TEST.pdf, 6a6db7307f98e87fbd6daf8d31887077f67163dd-1693899129413, null)
2023-09-05T09:32:09.455+02:00 INFO  o.b.p.PresentationUrlDownloadService - Validating redirect URL [https://bbb-conference.domain.com/b/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBYjQ9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--d3198043c54f5555051d8efc6077c711ee7a2b71/CHANGE_TEST.pdf]
2023-09-05T09:32:09.455+02:00 ERROR o.b.p.PresentationUrlDownloadService - Address [127.0.1.1] is a loopback address
2023-09-05T09:32:09.455+02:00 ERROR o.b.web.controllers.ApiController - Failed to download  ```

The above redirect URL is working and contains the expected PDF-File. 
For comparison, here is a log-extract from a working Setup running BBB 2.6.12 BUT with greenlight-V3 running under Root "/"  not "/b". Everything else is the same though:

2023-09-05T09:41:27.657+02:00 DEBUG o.b.web.controllers.ApiController - module config found: [presentation]
2023-09-05T09:41:27.657+02:00 DEBUG o.b.web.controllers.ApiController - ApiController#downloadAndProcessDocument(https://bbb-conf-dev.domain.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJaWxsTWprMk9HTTJNeTFoTldFNUxUUTFZekl0WW1Sak9TMHhPR00yTURRMVpHTmtORE1HT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImJsb2JfaWQifX0=--f356bfb04a8f2daf03f1754a1fd056dcc91ce4b8/CHANGE_TEST.pdf, 3aead6392bf989429fdb0112c57583053af0e0f1-1693899687622, null)
2023-09-05T09:41:27.658+02:00 INFO  o.b.p.PresentationUrlDownloadService - Validating redirect URL [https://bbb-conf-dev.domain.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJaWxsTWprMk9HTTJNeTFoTldFNUxUUTFZekl0WW1Sak9TMHhPR00yTURRMVpHTmtORE1HT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImJsb2JfaWQifX0=--f356bfb04a8f2daf03f1754a1fd056dcc91ce4b8/CHANGE_TEST.pdf]
2023-09-05T09:41:27.674+02:00 INFO  o.b.p.PresentationUrlDownloadService - Validating redirect URL [https://bbb-conf-dev.domain.com/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhZbXhvY2pVNFoyeDFhMjF1YTJObGRHVmhZVE4xTjNNMVpHcGhPQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpU1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWtOSVFVNUhSVjlVUlZOVUxuQmtaaUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuUTBoQlRrZEZYMVJGVTFRdWNHUm1CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lVWVhCd2JHbGpZWFJwYjI0dmNHUm1CanNHVkRvUmMyVnlkbWxqWlY5dVlXMWxPZ3BzYjJOaGJBPT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIzLTA5LTA1VDA3OjQ2OjI3LjY3MloiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--ca29d06c73ce9a983dfbfd3668a6965cc9e5f72f/CHANGE_TEST.pdf]
2023-09-05T09:41:27.704+02:00 INFO  o.b.p.PresentationUrlDownloadService - Redirected to Final URL [https://bbb-conf-dev.secunet.de/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhZbXhvY2pVNFoyeDFhMjF1YTJObGRHVmhZVE4xTjNNMVpHcGhPQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpU1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWtOSVFVNUhSVjlVUlZOVUxuQmtaaUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuUTBoQlRrZEZYMVJGVTFRdWNHUm1CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lVWVhCd2JHbGpZWFJwYjI0dmNHUm1CanNHVkRvUmMyVnlkbWxqWlY5dVlXMWxPZ3BzYjJOaGJBPT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIzLTA5LTA1VDA3OjQ2OjI3LjY3MloiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--ca29d06c73ce9a983dfbfd3668a6965cc9e5f72f/CHANGE_TEST.pdf]

We see here, that instead of complaining about the loopback adress, it redirects a couple of times and then accepts the PDF-File
````

I dont know why the system would suddenly decide to start worrying about a loopback address.

I anyone could point me in a direction as to where I should start looking for a problem I would be grateful.

Please let me know if I can provide any more information to get a better picture of what is happening here.

Regards,
Ollowain